# Equations of Trajectories of : $x'=1, y' = 2(1-x)\sin(1-x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Studying for my Dynamical Systems course, I came upon an exercise that I do not know how to proceed at :

**Exercise :**

> Find the Equations of the Trajectories of the system  : $x'=1, y' = 2(1-x)\sin(1-x^2)$

**Discussion :**

I've handled simpler systems, which have closed form solution and you can derive the trajectory equations, for example like, when a solution is $(\cos t, \sin t)$ the trajectory equation is the unit circle.

But in this particular exercise, despite that $x'=1$ has a simple and easy solution, the second differential equation cannot be solved in a known-function form way, as Wolfram Alpha says, which means that I do not know what to do in order to find the equations of the trajectories.

(Neither the substitution $\frac{dy}{dy} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ works because it's essentially the same differential equation)

I would really much appreciate some thorough help !

Comment: You know, an equation of type $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)$ is very far from unsolvable. I think you somehow overlooked that.

Comment: @Evgeny My question is, how can I find the equations of the trajectories of this system, that I'm being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation, you see that

$$x(t)=t+c_1$$

Using this for the second equation we obtain

$$y'(t)=2(1-t-c_1)\sin\left[1-(t+c_1)^2\right]$$

Integration is possible by introducing the Fresnel cosine and sine integrals

$$C(u)=\int_{0}^{u}\cos\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}\tau^2\right]\tau^2d\tau$$ 
$$S(u)=\int_{0}^{u}\sin\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2}\tau^2\right]\tau^2d\tau.$$

Using these definitions we obtain

$$y(t)= -\sqrt {2\pi} \left[ \cos  1 \,S
 \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( t+c_1 \right) }{\sqrt {\pi }}}
 \right) -\sin  1 \, C \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2
} \left( t+c_1 \right) }{\sqrt {\pi }}} \right)  \right] $$
$$-\cos
 \left( {c_1}^{2}+2\,tc_1+{t}^{2}-1 \right) +c_2.$$

Now resubstitute $t=x-c_1$ into $y(t)$ to eliminate time and to obtain $y(x)$ as

$$y(x)= -\sqrt {2\pi} \left[ \cos  1 \,S
 \left(\sqrt{2/\pi}x 
 \right) -\sin  1 \, C \left( \sqrt{2/\pi}x \right)  \right] $$
$$-\cos
 \left( {c_1}^{2}+2\,(x-c_1)c_1+(x-c_1)^{2}-1 \right)+c_2$$

$$= -\sqrt {2\pi} \left[ \cos  1 \,S
 \left(\sqrt{2/\pi}x 
 \right) -\sin  1 \, C \left( \sqrt{2/\pi}x \right)  \right]$$
$$-\cos
 \left(x^2-1\right)+c_2$$

I don't think that there is a way to express this result by using only elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

this is right what you have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$ and this $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2(1-x)\sin(1-x^2)$$ solve this equation.

Comment: It cannot get solved with ordinary functions : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx++%3D+2*(1-x)*sin(1-x%5E2)

Comment: then check if there is a typo in your equations

Comment: There is not a typo in the equations. The exercise comes from a well known Greek book about Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems.

Comment: It is also part of our big homework that we present as a small booklet, so it's 100% not wrong.

Comment: The reason I posted it as well is that usually this type of exercises that involve equations that cannot be solved within terms of usual function, have interesting ways to be worked around ! And I can't seem to find the way to solve it hehe.

Comment: have you a link to this book? or a Name?

Comment: you can assume that for small $x$ the $$\sin(1-x^2)\approx 1-x^2$$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a link as I have the physical version of it, the name translated to English (by me) is : "Differential Equations : Ordinary & Partial (Theory and Applications from nature and life)" . It's Greek name is : "Διαφορικές Εξισώσεις : Συνήθεις και Μερικές (Θεωρία και Εφαρμογές απο τη φύση και τη ζωή)" .

Comment: oh my Greec is not good enough, but i know the letters

Comment: I'll proceed with $\sin(1-x^2)\approx 1-x^2$ for small $x$ but something tells me there may be a different way of working around that. Our professor (the one who wrote the book) always likes this type of weird exercises !

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Can you share later what your professor said about this problem? It's clearly possible to write equations of trajectories, using definite integration or Fresnel functions, but it's pretty interesting where there is some workaround (still think that no, there isn't).

Comment: @Evgeny For sure, I will update you when he runs over the solution of this !

Comment: i'm also interested about the "Solutions" of this problems